# BASH script continues past EXIT command

Tags: bash

This is an example of part of a much larger bash (Fedora 30) script that shows the problem I am having

The script is supposed to traverse a directory tree and exit if it finds any filenames longer than 103 characters.

```
SS_NORMAL=0
JOLIET_MAX=103
MD5FILE=/tmp/blah.md5

function myExit
{
    echo Exiting $1 ...
    exit
}

function traverse
{
    find . -type f -print0 | 
       while IFS= read -r -d '' MD5_FILESPEC; do
          MD5_BASE=$(basename "$MD5_FILESPEC")
          if [ "${#MD5_BASE}" -gt "$JOLIET_MAX" ]; then
              myExit "[FAIL] Filename size ${#MD5_BASE} too long - $MD5_FILESPEC"
           fi
       done
}

traverse
date; date; date
```

It works fine until it finds one of those long filenames.  It calls myExit and it  exits the loop, but not all the way out of the script.  I always see the three dates at the end of the output, and I should not.

How can I handle this?

Comment: `|` - the right side of a pipe is in a subshell. Ex. try `echo | exit`.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand how I should try it.  Could you change my code in an answer so I can give you credit for it?

Comment: @JohnW : I think what KamilCuk wanted to say is that if you would do on the bash command line a `echo|exit`, you will see that it won't exit the bash either. You have to rewrite the logic of your script in a way that the `exit` is really done inside that process which you want to leave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy way to get around the problem that the `while` loop runs in a subprocess is to perpetrate a reversal: have `while` run in the same shell, an a sub-process to generate the files.

But how can we do that, if the receiver of the filenames from `find` has to be on the right of the `|` operator? The answer is that in GNU Bash, we have a language extension called "process substitution".

Process substitution is a piece of syntax that Bash converts into some string that looks looks and behaves like a file name, and is accepted that way by a command. When the program opens and reads that file (or, in the other direction, writes it), it communicates through a pipe with another process.

Sketch of the idea:

```
   while IFS= read -r -d '' MD5_FILESPEC; do
      MD5_BASE=$(basename "$MD5_FILESPEC")
      if [ "${#MD5_BASE}" -gt "$JOLIET_MAX" ]; then
          myExit "[FAIL] Filename size ${#MD5_BASE} too long - $MD5_FILESPEC"
       fi
   done < <(find . -type f -print0)
   #      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ this is the process substitution
```

Comment: +1, This is a good approach too. I have never used a pipe like in OP's script, it had me a confused for a minute.

Comment: @Z4-tier, in principle, when we have a command pipe like C1 | C2 | ...| CN, the shell could choose any one of the commands to use the same process, not necessarily the leftmost one. There should be a feature for indicating which pipeline element should be in the same process.

Comment: @Kaz bash doesn't run *any* part of a pipeline in the same process (except that `jobs | ...` [is a special case](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/279592/cannot-grep-jobs-list-when-jobs-called-in-a-function/279792#279792). I'd argue that process substitutions *are* a way to control this.

Comment: @Kaz - thanks, perfect answer.  I need to read up more on process substitution.  For people reading this answer, the last line should be `done < <(find . -type f -print0)`

Comment: @JohnW Ah, of course; `while` doesn't open a file name argument. :)

Answer (score 1):

As @KamilCuk mentioned, the pipe from `find` to `read` in the loop means the `exit` occurs in a sub-shell. Which is to say, when you have `find . -type f -print0 | <do some stuff>`, and `<do some stuff>` includes a call to `exit`, that `exit` applies within the subshell created by the `|`. In the case of your script, `myExit` is calling `exit` which ends the `while`-loop on the right side of the pipe, but this does not end the parent shell in which `traverse` was actually running. `traverse` then finishes, `date` is executed 3 times, and the script ends.

Probably the easiest option is to use `set -e` at the top of your script. This is kind of a scortched earth approach: if *anything* returns non-zero, the script will exit.

To do this, replace the entire `myExit` function with this:

```
set -e

function myExit() {
    echo "Exiting $1 ..."
    return 1
}
```

Now you will get a non-zero return code when calling that function from inside the loop, and the script should exit immediately.

A more forgiving approach is to change `myExit1` as above, but without adding `set -e`, and add a `return 1` immediately *after* the call to `myExit`:

```
if [ "${#MD5_BASE}" -gt "$JOLIET_MAX" ]; then
    myExit "[FAIL] Filename size ${#MD5_BASE} too long - $MD5_FILESPEC"
    return 1
fi
```

And change the call to `traverse` to this:

```
if ! traverse; then exit; fi
```

Now when the `if` block ever fires, it will call `myExit`, which calls `exit`, which terminates the subshell, at which point `traverse` returns a value of `1`, the `if` condition evaluates to `true`, and `exit` is called.

Another answer to your question suggests using *process substitution*, which is also good solution here. That shows the more typical pattern used for this type of loop operation:

```
while ... read ... ; do 
  ... 
done < (<input process>)
```

Finally, as matter of stylistic preference: I would probably get rid of `myExit` as a separate function, unless you have plans to expand it. As-is, it seems like it just creates unneeded complexity.